# .NET: How to deal with possible null values in an SQL query?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Code:

```
private void DoSomethingWithDatabase(string f1, int f2) 
{
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM MyTable WHERE Field1 = @F1 AND Field2 = @F2", this.myConn);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@F1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@F2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

    if (f1 == "") 
        myCommand.Parameters["@F1"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    else
        myCommand.Parameters["@F1"].Value = f1;

    if (f2 < 0)
        myCommand.Parameters["@F2"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    else
        myCommand.Parameters["@F2"].Value = f2;

    // code to do stuff with the results here
}
```

The server is a Microsoft SQL Server instance.

The database table `MyTable` contains fields which are nullable. Therefore null is a valid value to search on when performing the query.

From my reading, and also from testing code like this, doing something like what I did here doesn't work properly because apparently you can't do an "equals null" comparison this way - you're supposed to do "IS NULL".

It looks like you can correct this and make it work by setting ANSI_NULL to OFF (as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) but it also indicates this method is deprecated and should not be used.

That article suggests you can use an OR operator to do something like `WHERE Field1 = 25 OR Field1 IS NULL`. The problem is, with a single call to this function, I want to check for *either* null and only null, or for the given constant value and nothing else.

So far, it seems like I need to basically build the query piece by piece, string by string, to account for the possibility of NULL values. So I'd need to do something like:

```
string theQuery = "SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM MyTable WHERE ";
if (f1 == "")
    theQuery += "Field1 IS NULL ";
else
    theQuery += "Field1 = @F1 ";

// ...

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(theQuery, this.myConn);
if (f1 == "")
{
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@F1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    myCommand.Parameters["@F1"].Value = f1;
}

// ...
```

Is this really how it needs to be done? Is there a more efficient way to do this without repeating that `if` block and by using parameters rather than concatenating a query string together?

(Notes: An empty string is converted to a NULL here for the example. In the scenario I'm actually working with, empty strings are never used, but instead NULL is stored. The database is out of my control, so I can't just say "change all your NULLs to empty strings". Same goes for the ints - if we pass, say, `-1` into the function it should be testing for a null value. Bad practice? Maybe, but the database itself is not in my control, only the code to access it is.)

Comment: Be wary of the answers suggesting ISNULL or COALESCE in the WHERE clause. You will likely want to create an index to make this query faster (something like Field1, Field2 INCLUDE Field3) and ISNULL/COALESCE will stop the index being used. What you suggest in your final code block looks fine and I think is better than any of the given answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using:

```
string theQuery = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM MyTable WHERE ISNULL(Field1,'') = @F1";
```

?

That way you get rid of your if block and your null values are interpreted as an empty string, like your `f1` variable.

Comment: So would I do something like `SELECT ISNULL(Field1,'') as Field1 FROM MyTable WHERE Field1 = @F1`? And then if I assigned an empty string to the F1 parameter, it would evaluate to true? If so this sounds like it's exactly what I need...!

Comment: But this way the query will not return rows where the field is null. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak With ANSI_NULL ON, the condition Field1 = NULL is never true

Comment: @MartínMisol Oops, you're right. I have edited my answer, the `ISNULL()` function wasn't at the good place. It has be in the `WHERE` ...

Comment: @Kabulan0lak Now it works, but Andy Nichols is right with his comment, if the column has an index using ISNULL on your filter would prevent the index from being used.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a function called `ISNULL(Column,Value)` where you can specify one column to check and set a Default Value in case this Column is NULL.
You can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184325(v=SQL.120).aspx)

Comment: Your link goes to the Brazilian Portuguese version of the documentation. The en-us version is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(v=SQL.120).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
WHERE ISNULL(Field, '') = @F1
```

In that case, `NULL` fields are treated like empty strings. Another way would be:

```
WHERE Field IS NULL OR Field = @1
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are dealing with NULLs is the right way. Maybe you could use a helper method like this one:

```
private string AppendParameter(string query, string parameterName, string parameterValue, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterValue))
         query += "Field1 IS NULL ";
     else
     {
         query += "Field1 = " + parameterName + " ";
         parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, parameterValue);
     }

     return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 
     FROM MyTable 
     WHERE 
     ( (@F1 IS NULL AND [field1] IS NULL) OR [field1] = @F1 ) AND
     ( (@F2 IS NULL AND [field2] IS NULL) OR [field2] = @F2 );", this.myconn);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@F1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@F2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f1))
      myCommand.Parameters["@F1"].Value = f1;
    if (f2 != -1)
      myCommand.Parameters["@F2"].Value = f2;
```

This would utilize indexes on fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid if blocks, you can probably change the query into something like this:

```
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM MyTable 
WHERE COALESCE(Field1,'') = @F1 AND COALESCE(Field2,-1) = @F2
```